# How to count the off-diagonal elements?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix which I need to extract values from off-diagonal of this matrix. However, in the R code below, I wrote a code that just reads the rows of the matrix. How could I correct my R code? Assuming each of row in matrix is corresponding to one individual, the values are the correlation between 2 individuals.for example, I want to know in row 1 of the matrix "var", how many of the elements are above 0.80 so on and so for.

```
var<-matrix(c(1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.9,1,0.7,0.8,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.5,0.4,0.7,
              0.8,0.5,1,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,1),ncol=5)


rowmatrix=1:nrow(var)
OUT=NULL        

for (x in rowmatrix) {                       
  row=c(var[x,])
  count<-sum(row>=0.8)
  count1<-count-1
  if(count1 < 0) {
    count1=0 
  }

  output=cbind(x,count,count1)                        
  OUT <<- rbind(OUT,output)

}

colnames(OUT) <- c("index.ind","countrow","countrow_withoutdiag")
OUT
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: for example, in matrix "var", I want to know how many of the values of the matrix have value bigger than 0.80. I were able to calculate the row part of the matrix however because of the symmetry of the matrix I have a problem to set up the column part in the code.

Comment: This question is really unclear. What about `head(rowSums(replace(var, lower.tri(var,diag=TRUE), NA) >= 0.8, na.rm=TRUE),-1)` ?

Comment: Assuming each of row in matrix is corresponding to one individual, the values are the correlation between 2 individuals. if you run my R code and print the "OUT", you can see the index.ind which is for each row and the second column counts the number of values that are greater than 0.80 but it is included the lower diagonal matrix.

Comment: What you want is the number of the off-diagonal elements of the upper and the lower matrices that are superior or equal to 0.8. I understand now and posted a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
> sum(var[lower.tri(var)] > 0.8)
[1] 1
> (sum(var > 0.8) - sum(diag(var) > .8))/2
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives you what you want:

```
lowcount <- rowSums(replace(var, upper.tri(var,diag=TRUE), NA) >= 0.8, na.rm=TRUE)
uppcount <- rowSums(replace(var, lower.tri(var,diag=TRUE), NA) >= 0.8, na.rm=TRUE)
cbind(OUT,lowcount,uppcount)

#     index.ind countrow countrow_withoutdiag lowcount uppcount
#[1,]         1        3                    2        0        2
#[2,]         2        3                    2        1        1
#[3,]         3        2                    1        1        0
#[4,]         4        2                    1        1        0
#[5,]         5        1                    0        0        0
```

As you can see, adding `lowcount` + `uppcount` matches with your existing `countrow_withoutdiag` - so the figures seem valid.

Comment: Your answer is faster. Why am I still writing `for`loops... ^^

Comment: @Ouistiti - because sometimes they're simpler :-)

Comment: I think the OP wants to count the occurences of [,] >= 0.8 by columns for the upper triangular matrix, although he did not express it.

Answer (score 0):

To count how many elements are >= 0.8 do:

```
sum(var>=.8)
```

This will include any element on the diagonal that meets the criteria.
If you don't want to count them, substract `sum(diag(var)>=.8)`:

```
sum(var>=.8) - sum(diag(var)>=.8)
```

**Count how many elements are above the threshhold for every row but limited to the upper diagonal**
I'll edit your program to get the above count.

```
var<-matrix(c(1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.9,1,0.7,0.8,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.5,0.4,0.7,
              0.8,0.5,1,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,1),ncol=5)

# don't include the last row (it has no element above the diagonal)
rowmatrix = 1:(nrow(var)-1)

OUT = NULL

for (x in rowmatrix) {                       
  # The row will subset the current row with columns from x+1 to end
  row = var[x,(x+1):nrow(var)]
  count <- sum(row >= 0.8)
  # since the diagonal element is not in the subset these lines are no longer needed.
  # "count" is now the number of elements >= 0.8 without the diagonal

  # count1<-count-1
  #if(count1 < 0) {
  #  count1=0 
  #}

  # if we assume diagonal elements equal to 1 then the next line changes to:
  output=cbind(x,count + 1, count)

  OUT <<- rbind(OUT,output)

}

colnames(OUT) <- c("index.ind","countrow","countrow_withoutdiag")
OUT
```

And the result:

```
> OUT
     index.ind countrow countrow_withoutdiag
[1,]         1        3                    2
[2,]         2        2                    1
[3,]         3        1                    0
[4,]         4        1                    0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this does not meet my need

Comment: @user4665665 Explain why it doesn't meet your needs and you're more likely to get the help you want

Comment: for example, in matrix "var", I want to know how many of the values of row matrix have value bigger than 0.80. I were able to calculate the row part of the matrix however because of the symmetry of the matrix I have a problem to set up the column part in the code

Comment: As I stated in my answer, this works for any numeric matrix, square or not, symmetric or not.  If your matrix is square AND symmetric, and you want to count how many element above the diagonal are greater than a threshhold, then divide by two the answer given by the last command.

Comment: Assuming each of row in matrix is corresponding to one individual, the values are the correlation between 2 individuals. if you run my R code and print the "OUT", you can see the index.ind which is for each row and the second column counts the number of values that are greater than 0.80 but it is included the lower diagonal matrix.

Comment: @R.Schifini Thanks for your modification. it seems this time counting values from upper diagonal from certain limitation works.

Answer (score 0):

I have got what you are looking for:

```
lower<-var*lower.tri(var,diag=FALSE)
for (i in 1:(nrow(var))){
  print(paste("Row ", i," has ",length(which(lower[i,]>=0.8))," values superior or equal to 0.8"))
}

upper<-var*upper.tri(var,diag=FALSE)
for (i in 1:(nrow(var))){
  print(paste("Row ", i," has ",length(which(upper[i,]>=0.8))," values superior or equal to 0.8"))
}
```

## *EDIT*

if you want to count per column for the upper triangular matrix, then:

```
upper<-var*upper.tri(var,diag=FALSE)
    for (i in 1:(ncol(var))){
      print(paste("Column ", i," has ",length(which(upper[,i]>=0.8))," values superior or equal to 0.8"))
    }
```

Comment: If you run your suggestion code and compare to "var" matrix, it seems lower triangle works but the counting for upper diagonal is wrong.

Comment: No @thelatemail found the same results.